# Python3 turtle how to wait until keypress

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a simple game written in Python3 turtle
When game finished I want to show message 'Continue? (y/n)' and wait until user press a button on the keyboard. Any ideas how can implement a wait feature?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Turtle to wait for a pressed key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269201/how-do-i-make-turtle-to-wait-for-a-pressed-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `textinput` method:

```
def textinput(self, title, prompt):
    """Pop up a dialog window for input of a string.

    Arguments: title is the title of the dialog window,
    prompt is a text mostly describing what information to input.

    Return the string input
    If the dialog is canceled, return None.

    Example (for a TurtleScreen instance named screen):
    >>> screen.textinput("NIM", "Name of first player:")

    """
    return simpledialog.askstring(title, prompt)
```

Comment: Already test this feature. Not that what I want. I've solve the problem by adding new scene to the game. But thank you for response

Comment: what is this "simpledialog"? It doesn't seem to come with the turtle module.